# Is there an alternative for xinetd that supports control characters?

Tags: telnet, xinetd

I am writing a project that allows users to connect in and run specific commands. xinetd is an option but pressing `Tab` via either nc or telnet will type an indentation.

Is there a net daemon that can regard `Tab` as a control character (when using telnet or other free software client)?

P.S. My xinetd config is like

```
service ctf
{
    server = /bin/bash
    port = 2333
    protocol = tcp
    type = UNLISTED
    user = root
    wait = no
    flags = NODELAY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TAB`, `0x09`, `011`, `\t`, <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> is NOT affected by `xinetd`. Once `xinetd` invokes the server, it doesn't touch the stream. The stream is "8-bit clean". TAB interpretation is left to the invoked server.

However, since `/bin/bash` doesn't accept TCP/IP packets on its `STDIN`, this is never going to work. That's why the Telnet Protocol was invented